# Where are running setTimeout stored?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, callstack, event-loop

So I get it that `setTimeout` stores the passed callback function in the task queue after the specified amount of milliseconds. My question is where are those ticking timers are stored? E.g.:

```
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

After ~1 second func is moved to the task queue and after that - in the JS stack. But what about the duration between `setTimeout` call and moving `func` to the task queue? Where `func` is stored **during** this second?

Please correct me if I've written something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: in the javascript engine :p

Comment: Web API in case of browser, i guess.

Comment: to be honest, things like this have no impact on your code, so, unless you're writing you're own javascript engine, is there really a "need to know"? like ... where are the contents of arrays stored ... in some memory, somewhere, but does it matter? do all javascript engines work the same (no) ... with jacascript, there are far better things to concern yourself with than how the internals work :p (that's just my opinion, no harm no foul intended)

Comment: You can also assign them to a variable like `var t = setTimeout(f, n)`, with which you can work later like `clearTimeout(t)`.

Comment: @Rod911 - in browsers at least Firefox, `setTimeout` simply returns a number - so .. that isn't the "timeout code waiting to time out" :p I think OP wants to know where the setTimeout "waits" to "trigger"? I think it just does

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849542/how-does-libuv-and-node-js-actually-schedule-timers for node specifically. BTW, your question ought to specify exactly which environment you're interested in, since various environments may implement this slightly differently (though AFAICT main browsers actually do the same as node more or less).

Comment: @Kaiido this is what I've been looking for:) So the callbacks are stored outside of the "JS world". Thanks for the clarification. Should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the specs, there is a [List of Active Timers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#list-of-active-timers) that should exist for objects that implement the [`WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope` mixin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#windoworworkerglobalscope) (in other words, the list should exist in the `window` object of a browser), however, it seems that it is not accessible. There has been other questions around this matter (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921071/how-to-get-the-list-of-active-timers-of-a-windowtimer-implemented-object)).

In any case, if you have an extreme need to keep track of the active timers (it is the same list for `setInterval` and `setTimeout`) ,(internally, `setInterval` works the same as `setTimeout`, but with a `repeat` flag), you can try proxy those methods.

Something like this:

(This example can be extended and much more data could be stored in the `activeTimers` set like `id`, `handler`, `duration` and even some helper methods to trigger or abort each timer or all timers at once. The following should respect the specs.)

```js
(() => {
  const activeTimers = new Set();
  const _setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
  const _setInterval = window.setInterval;
  const _clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
  const _clearInterval = window.clearInterval;
  
  window.setTimeout = (cb, duration) => {
    let id = -1;
    
    const wrapper = (...args) => {
      activeTimers.delete(id);
      cb(...args);
    }
    
    id = _setTimeout(wrapper, duration);
    
    activeTimers.add(id);
    
    return id;
  };
  
  window.setInterval = (cb, duration) => {
    const id = _setInterval(cb, duration);
    activeTimers.add(id);
    return id;
  };
  
  window.clearTimeout = (id) => {
    _clearTimeout(id);
    activeTimers.delete(id);
  };
  
  window.clearInterval = (id) => {
    _clearInterval(id);
    activeTimers.delete(id);
  };
  
  // YOU CAN EXPORT THIS METHOD FROM A MODULE INSTEAD OF ADDING IT TO THE window OBJECT.
  window.getActiveTimers = () => {
    return Array.from(activeTimers.values());
  };
})();

// USAGE:

console.log('INITIAL TIMERS:', getActiveTimers());

// EXAMPLE 1

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('TIMER 1 FINISHED:', getActiveTimers());
}, 1000);
console.log('TIMER 1 ADDED: ', getActiveTimers().toString());

// EXAMPLE 2

const timer2Id = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('TIMER 2 FINISHED:', getActiveTimers());
}, 1000);
console.log('TIMER 2 ADDED: ', getActiveTimers().toString());

clearTimeout(timer2Id);
console.log('TIMER 2 REMOVED: ', getActiveTimers().toString());

// EXPECTED OUTPUT ORDER: [] -> 1 -> 1,2 -> 1 -> []
```

Comment: That doesn't explain where it is stored. The specs "List of Active Timers" doesn't say how implementers should keep track of the callback function and all its closures. Also, your code doesn't reproduce setTimeout and setInterval correctly.

Comment: @Kaiido I guess saying that it is not well specified is part of the answer. Just fixed the code btw, I was missing the return statements.

Comment: Why should that be specified? The question asks how it is implemented, not how it is specified. And your code still doesn't eval correctly. `setTimeout("alert('I am horrible, but I work...')", 0)`

Comment: @Kaiido it is just a didactic example of how to proxy those methods, not a replacement recommendation. The question is literally "Where are running setTimeout stored?" and I posted the more specific information that is available about that. I can't makeup an answer, things are like they are. Everyone here is doing their best to contribute and the ultimate goal of this platform is to collectively create knowledge. Should know that already.

Comment: Yes I know that, and my goal is exactly to get "the best" knowledge as possible. Hand waving things like that doesn't produce the best knowledge, stating that "The following should respect the specs." when it doesn't even reproduce the basics of what any documentation will provide is also worth a comment don't you think?